# Cookie is not available to the server after redirect

Tags: c#, javascript, cookies, web

I am trying setting a Cookie in my browser, just to make sure I alert the value of the cookie just after that and it does have a cookie. After that i redirect my location to Google and after Google authenticated, control goes to the server.

Now Server does not have a value in this particular request. BUT strangely server has a value of cookie on all the subsequent requests.

Here is some Client code:

```
cookies.SetCookie('CampaignToken', data.CampaignToken, '12/06/2013 00:00:00', '/');
                    alert(cookies.GetCookie('CampaignToken').toString());
                    window.location = data.GoogleRequestURL;
```

Here is some server Code, which is executed after control comes back from Google:

```
  if (Request.Cookies["CampaignToken"] != null)
            {
                var cookie = Request.Cookies["CampaignToken"].Value;
                Response.Cookies.Remove("CampaignToken");

                return Redirect(Request.Url + "/" + cookie);
            }
```

Thing to note here is that Request.Cookies["CampaignToken"]  returns null for the first time and then it returns the value of the cookie. Also, cookie has a value when I do an alert on the client just before going to Google.

Comment: One thing to note here is that Cookie is available if I refresh the page. But google redirect seems to cause the problem..

Comment: I think this cookie is acting as a session cookie which is only available only when I am on the same session. In this case, I switch to Google, session changes and then I come back, session changed. So Cookie is gone. One thing I don't understand is that I am setting the expiry explicitly on that and as far as my understanding is there I am setting up a persistent Cookie. But it does not seem to act as one......